# Sync calls from Swift to C based thread-unsafe library

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, blocking

My Swift code needs to call some C functions that are not thread safe. All calls need to be:

1) synchronous (sequential invocation of function, only after previous call returned),

2) on the same thread.

I've tried to create a queue and then access C from within a function:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.app.thread-1", qos: .userInitiated)

func calc(...) -> Double {
    var result: Double!
    queue.sync {
        result = c_func(...)
    }
    return result
}
```

This has improved the behaviour yet I still get crashes - sometimes, not as often as before and mostly while debugging from Xcode.
Any ideas about better handling?

**Edit**

Based on the comments below, can somebody give an general example of how to use a thread class to ensure sequential execution on the same thread?

**Edit 2**

A good example of the problem can be seen when using this wrapper around C library:
https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-PostgreSQL

It works fine when accessed from a single queue. But will start producing weird errors if several dispatch queues are involved.

So I am envisaging an approach of a single executor thread, which, when called, would block the caller, perform calculation, unblock the caller and return result. Repeat for each consecutive caller.

Something like this:

```
thread 1     |              |
--------->   |              | ---->
thread 2     | executor     |      ---->
--------->   | thread       |
thread 3     | -----------> |
--------->   |              |            ---->
...
```

Comment: What's the crash stack trace?

Comment: The crash happens within C function. It's not, technically speaking, a crash, the C function simply calls abort() and exits because its internal stack of invocations order isn't right. Meaning instead of expected "a" -> "b" -> "c", it sees something like "a" -> "d" -> "e" -> "b" -> "c" call sequence. To me it looks like Swift queue called C function from a different thread.

Comment: Maybe the `c_func(...)` has asynchronous internal code?

Comment: Just checked, it doesn't use any calls to pthread or relates to threads in general. Ignoring the C library, do you think my way to handle this kind of situation via a queue is correct? Or is there a better way to stay on the same thread and be synchronous?

Comment: Also made me thinking if `DispatchQueue` changes threads under the hood?

Comment: Using DispatchQueue doesn't guarantee that the block will be run on the same thread every time. All it guarantees is that the sync block won't be ever run concurrently with any other block on the same synchronous queue. It is entirely possible that GCD decides to run the code on a separate thread.

Comment: Thanks @hhanesand it makes sense. So what would be a better design pattern to ensure sync + same thread execution? Should I go all way down to thread/semaphores or is there a higher level API for this kind of situation?

Comment: I don't think there is an API for same-thread sync on iOS, so yeah, you might have to drop down. BTW, to me it seems a little weird that the C code requires "same thread" (thread-safe != same thread). I'm not experienced with C at all, but could it be possible that the crash you're seeing could be the result of something else? We could help you if you post it here.

Comment: @hhanesand Got it. Hoping somebody can share a code snippet if they had an experience similar to this one. The C library in question simply keeps track of invocations of its core functions. So if one of its functions gets called from within another Swift thread context, the call stack order gets out of whack and the library complains. It's as simple as that. From what I see, it has nothing to do with the library as such, rather how I structure Swift code.

Comment: @DenisZubkov does the C function make use of thread local variables? As others pointed out, DispatchQueues (except for the main queue) aren't pinned to a specific thread. Also:
You could rewrite the function much easier this way:

```func calc(...) -> Double {
    return queue.sync { c_func(...); }
}```

as `DispatchQueue.sync` returns the closures result.

Comment: @JohannesWeiß I can see that the problem occurs when DispatchQueue switches threads under the hood (very rarely). The C library doesn't seem to use thread local variables, rather preserves its state internally. I've added an example of PostgreSQL wrapper with which I had a similar problem. Yeah, it's a tricky case...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *really* need to ensure that all API calls must come from a single thread, you can do so by using the [`Thread`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/thread) class plus [some synchronization primitives](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsemaphore).

For instance, a somewhat straightforward implementation of such idea is provided by the `SingleThreadExecutor` class below:

```swift
class SingleThreadExecutor {

    private var thread: Thread!
    private let threadAvailability = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

    private var nextBlock: (() -> Void)?
    private let nextBlockPending = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    private let nextBlockDone = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    init(label: String) {
        thread = Thread(block: self.run)
        thread.name = label
        thread.start()
    }

    func sync(block: @escaping () -> Void) {
        threadAvailability.wait()

        nextBlock = block
        nextBlockPending.signal()
        nextBlockDone.wait()
        nextBlock = nil

        threadAvailability.signal()
    }

    private func run() {
        while true {
            nextBlockPending.wait()
            nextBlock!()
            nextBlockDone.signal()
        }
    }
}
```

A simple test to ensure the specified *block* is really being called by a single thread:

```swift
let executor = SingleThreadExecutor(label: "single thread test")
for i in 0..<10 {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        executor.sync { print("\(i) @ \(Thread.current.name!)") }
    }
}
Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5) /* Wait for calls to finish. */
```

```
0 @ single thread test
1 @ single thread test
2 @ single thread test
3 @ single thread test
4 @ single thread test
5 @ single thread test
6 @ single thread test
7 @ single thread test
8 @ single thread test
9 @ single thread test
```

Finally, replace `DispatchQueue` with `SingleThreadExecutor` in your code and let's hope this fixes your — very exotic! — issue ;)

```swift
let singleThreadExecutor = SingleThreadExecutor(label: "com.example.app.thread-1")

func calc(...) -> Double {
    var result: Double!
    singleThreadExecutor.sync {
        result = c_func(...)
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Excellent! I have thoroughly tested the solution in a playground and it worked really well. Can add this case to "exotic patterns" handbook: https://gist.github.com/deze333/23d11123f02e65c456d16ffe5621e2ee

Comment: @DenisZubkov Nice, glad it solved your issue man! Please feel free to copy-and-paste my code around just remember to link back here for easy reference... which I believe you just did in your Gist ;)

Comment: Did some benchmarking, closures turn out to be such performance hogs! See my post below. That's for performance fun only. You answer is certainly and fully correct.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting outcome... I benchmarked performance of solution by Paulo Mattos that I have accepted vs my own earlier experiments where I used a much less elegant and lower level run loop & object reference approach to achieve the same pattern.

Playground for closure based approach:
https://gist.github.com/deze333/23d11123f02e65c456d16ffe5621e2ee

Playground for run loop & reference passing approach:
https://gist.github.com/deze333/82c0ee3e82fd250097449b1b200b7958

Using closures:

```
Invocations processed    : 1000
Invocations duration, sec: 4.95894199609756
Cost per invocation, sec : 0.00495894199609756
```

Using run loop and passing object reference:

```
Invocations processed    : 1000
Invocations duration, sec: 1.62595099210739
Cost per invocation, sec : 0.00162432666544195
```

Passing closures is x3 times slower due to them being allocated on the heap vs reference passing. This really confirms the performance problem of closures outlined in an excellent [Mutexes and closure capture in Swift](https://www.cocoawithlove.com/blog/2016/06/02/threads-and-mutexes.html) article.

The lesson: don't overuse closures when maximum performance in needed, which is often the case in mobile development.

Closures are so beautifully looking though!

**EDIT:**

Things are much better in Swift 4 with whole module optimisation. Closures are fast!

Comment: Interesting analysis... but are you doing all these benchmarks using *release mode* builds? Keep in mind that *Playgrounds* aren’t exactly the best place to be doing serious benchmarking... also: be sure to tweak Swift compiler optimization flags to get the best performance.